# Is there anything I can do with the implicit grid that I can't do with the explicit grid?

Tags: css, css-grid

We have the implicit grid with `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns`. We however can also use `grid-template-rows`/`grid-template-columns` in combination with `repeat` and `auto-fit` to create an explicit implicit grid.

Is there anything we can *only* do with `grid-auto-*` and *not* with `grid-template-*` in combination with `repeat` and `auto-fill`/`auto-fit`?

If yes is there a way to specify explicit^rows/columns *after* the implicit ones?

Like I have 3 explicit rows, then the implicit grid (because I need it because of the thing I cant do with explicit grid) and then one explicit row.

Comment: https://css-tricks.com/difference-explicit-implicit-grids/ i think it will be better just to provide an useful article

Comment: actually this was one of the articles that led to my need for clarification.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there anything I can do with the implicit grid that I can't do with the explicit grid?

Yes. The implicit grid handles grid items whose presence or placement is *unpredictable*. That's the primary benefit of the implicit grid. An explicit grid is limited to grid items whose presence or placement is *predictable*.

> We have the implicit grid with `grid-auto-rows` and `grid-auto-columns`. We however can also use `grid-template-rows` / `grid-template-columns` in combination with `repeat` and `auto-fit` to create an explicit implicit grid.

Your second sentence is not entirely correct.

There is nothing "implicit" (as the term is [defined in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#implicit-grids)) about `grid-template-rows`  / `grid-template-columns` in combination with `repeat` and `auto-fit` or `auto-fill`. The `repeat()` notation represents a predictable track pattern. This makes it fully "explicit" (again, as the term is [defined in the spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-grid-layout/#explicit-grids)).

> Is there anything we can *only* do with `grid-auto-*` and *not* with `grid-template-*` in combination with `repeat` and `auto-fill`/`auto-fit`?

The answer is no, if all columns and rows of the grid are known beforehand.

The answer is yes, if all columns and rows of the grid are not known beforehand.

> If yes is there a way to specify explicit^rows/columns *after* the implicit ones?
>
> Like I have 3 explicit rows, then the implicit grid (because I need it because of the thing I can't do with explicit grid) and then one explicit row.

Possibly. You would have to show a code sample.

Imagine a grid with three explicit rows — header, content, footer.

But the number of rows in the content section is unknown.

In that case, you can do something like this:

```
#container {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
}

#content {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
}
```

Here's a complete example:

```css
body {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-rows: 50px auto 50px;
  height: 100vh;
  margin: 0;
}

main {
  display: grid;
  grid-auto-rows: 200px;
  overflow: auto;
  background-color: gray;
}

main > article:nth-child(even) {
  background-color: aqua;
}

header { background-color: lightgreen; }
main   { background-color: orangered;  }
footer { background-color: gray;       }
body   { font-size: 1.1em; margin: 0;  }
```

```html
<header>header</header>
<main>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
  <article>content</article>
</main>
<footer>footer</footer>
```